# Traceback headers: "most recent call last" vs "innermost last"

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, traceback

Could anyone explain when a runtime error would generate a traceback with header `most recent call last` and when it would generate the header `innermost last`?

Comment: A quick google suggests that the latter is used by old versions of CPython (see, eg, the [Python 1.5.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2/tut/node10.html)), and possibly by Jython. But - don't these mean the same thing? It seems likely that it would be something that was changed simply for clarity of explaination somewhere along the line.

Comment: I think that is correct. Most traceback posts I can find with `innermost last` are indeed of quite a few years ago. I didn't figure it out myself immediately because I saw some recently published courses with that contain `innermost last`. But they probably just copied some code from older versions of those courses.
Would you leave an answer entry so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two terms are synonyms, so there's no apparent reason why the interpreter might give both of them alternatively. It seems like CPython, at least, used to always use "innermost last", and now always uses "most recent call last" - eg, the [Python 2.0 Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/tut/node10.html) uses "innermost", but this changed to "most recent" in the same example from the [Python 2.1 Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.1/tut/node10.html). I can't find any stated reason for the change (it isn't mentioned in the [Python 2.1 Release Notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.1/NEWS.txt)), but it seems likely that the devs just thought the new wording clearer.